# Cypher - get the latest node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here's my model:
`(:A)<--(:B)<-[:R {timestamp}]-(:C {number})`

What I'm trying to achieve in one cypher query is to get the latest C nodes, according to the latest R.timestamp (or C.number) for a given A and all the B nodes. That is returning one A, multiple Bs and one C related to each B with the highest R.timestamp. The best would be to also return B nodes without any relation to C.

In SQL I would group by and rank to return only the n rows that I wish per group, I don't have enough experience with COLLECT or UNWIND to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find your `a` node and then optionally match on the `b` and `c` nodes. This will also find `b` nodes that don't have a relationship to `a`.

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE a.name = {name}
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:C)-[:R]->(b:B)-[:R]->(a)
WITH a, b, c
ORDER BY c.number
WITH a, b, last(collect(c)) AS most_recent_c
RETURN a, b, most_recent_c;
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. I didn't spot the `last()` function. Alternatively, it would possible to play along with the order (DESC or ASC) and switch `last()` with `head()`. (c.f. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-function).

Now, this does not return the B nodes without C related to. I'll investigate and post result here.

Comment: I manage to have it working with both filtering on a relation property and including dead-end Bs:
`MATCH (a:A {name: {param}})<--(b:B)
with a, b
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:C)-[r:R]->(b) // ignore missing C
WITH a, b, r, c
ORDER BY r.end DESC
WITH a, b, head(collect(c)) as most_recent_c, head(collect(r)) as most_recent_r
RETURN a, b, most_recent_c, most_recent_r;`